# Passing variable to left hand side

Tags: r

In R, is there a way to pass the variable to the left hand side. For example

```
> x1 <- "yearly"
> paste0(x1,"_abs_sam") <- 2
```

> Error in paste0(x1, "_abs_sam") <- 2 : could not find function
> "paste0<-"

Expected output

```
yearly_abs_sam
2
```

So basically, I am passing x1 to create a variable here so instead of creating like

```
yearly_abs_sam <- 2
```

Comment: ``assign(paste0(x1,"_abs_sam"), 2)``

Comment: While that's the way to do what you asked, I *generally* (not always) recommend against the use of `assign` in this fashion, it often reflects an inefficient workflow. If you explain why you think this is what you ultimately want to do, perhaps we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: So basically there are lot of variable i need to create starting with "yearly" Like yearly_abs_sam, yearly_abs_sdf, yearly_abs_poi, yearly_abs_uio and so. So instead of hard coding it, I can just pass a variable. Make sense?

Comment: Yes. Would it make better send to have a `yearly` variable with named entries, such as `yearly <- c(abs_sam=2, abs_dfs=4, abs_poi=17)`? You'd then access it as `yearly['abs_sam']`. Either a `c(...)` or `list(...)` will work here, a list will be necessary if you have other than single-numbers to assign to each name.

Comment: Yes. But this ````year['abs_sam']```` returns a header

Comment: It returns a named value which may look like a header. See that `year['abs_sam'] + 1` returns another number. In R, a named number is still just a number, you can do anything number-like with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assign()`, although as r2evans suggests, using it is a bit of a code-smell and suggests you probably could do with changing your workflow.

```
assign(paste0(x1,"_abs_sam"), 2)
```

```
> yearly_abs_sam
[1] 2
```